# Google App Engine: Modify Cloud Run Environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a Next.js app which uses a custom Node.js server.

I want to inject custom build variables into the app:

#### next.config.js

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const envType = NODE_ENV === `production` ? `production` : `staging`;

const envPath = `./config/${envType}`;
const { env } = require(envPath);

module.exports = {
  env: { ...env },
};
```

The above file is run at build time (`yarn build`).

The issue is that Google App Engine uses Cloud Build behind the scenes. There, the `NODE_ENV` is always set to `development`. How can I override the `NODE_ENV` there; i.e. how can I customize the Cloud Build used for the Google App Engine `gcloud app deploy`?

I can't just use Docker because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885235/next-js-infinite-reload-from-docker-container).

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=staging node server.js",
    "build": "rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn && rm -rf .next/ && next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js",
    "gcp-build": "yarn build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "firebase": "^5.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "next": "^8.1.0",
    "now": "^15.0.6",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "session-file-store": "^1.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "yenv": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x.x"
  }
}
```

#### app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

### image

Below is the output of passing a `DOGE_ENV` variable from `app.yaml`. As you can see, it is `undefined`. However, `NODE_ENV` is `development`.

That is, adding the following to `app.yaml` does not work.

```
env_variables:
  DOGE_ENV: production
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Google Cloud Build to compile your yarn resources prior to your application running in Cloud Run/AppEngine? Or is this a running process that is spawned within the running Cloud Run/AppEngine instance?

Comment: Cloud build runs `yarn build` which builds the app which is served by `node server.js`. I'm not actually using Cloud Build directly, but all `gcloud app deploy`s have an associated Cloud Build using the `runtime` declared in `app.yaml` (in this case `runtime: nodejs10`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use NODE_ENV, create your own environment variable and use that:

**App.yaml**

```
env_variables:
  ST_ENV: Production
```

**next.config.js**

```
const environment = process.env.ST_ENV;
const envType = environment === `production` ? `production` : `staging`;

const envPath = `./config/${envType}`;
const { env } = require(envPath);

module.exports = {
  env: { ...env },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work because the Cloud Build environment is the build time environment, and the `env_variables` specified in `app.yaml` are runtime variables. So, `process.env.ST_ENV` will be `undefined` when `next.config.js` actually runs.

Comment: I've added an image of Cloud Build output which demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, at the end I solved setting `NODE_ENV=production` in the package.json script, so in your case just use:

```json
{
  "gcp-build": "NODE_ENV=production yarn build"
}
```

otherwise you can create a Cloud Build configuration file, check [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration), it supports an `env` section where you can define environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up using an approach similar to [Luca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64446135/6177468), but with a mechanism to substitute the correct variable in `package.json` before the deploy (using the [`microsoft/variable-substitution`](https://github.com/microsoft/variable-substitution) GitHub action in my case).